# Bunyan is displaying /n in the output .!

Tags: node.js, mongodb, hapi.js

I am using bunyan logs to display my messages . Its displaying \n in the output after every key-value pair . How to remove it ? Following is the screen shot of the output .
 [here is the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kCu8T.png)

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is just formatting. The text has line-changes which is displayed by the newline character "\n". Everything after the newline character should be displayed on the next line. Since this is just a string the terminal doesn't know how to display it.

If you have bunyan installed globally, you can pipe that response through bunyan cli.

`node runsomething.js | bunyan`

OR you don't have to have it globally installed if you run it through an npm script.

package.json

```
{
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node runsomething.js | bunyan",
  }
}
```

and run it via the start command
`npm start`

Relevant documentation: https://github.com/trentm/node-bunyan#cli-usage

Comment: Thank you. It worked on my system . will it also works on the production server ?

Comment: The best way to get it working on production system is to use a npm script. Just like the example i gave you. Then you don't need to worry about anything.

Comment: Thank you once again . All the log data of all levels is displayed in blue color only the level names differ in color . Is there any way to change the log data colors ? like error data should be red , debug yellow  or something like that !

Comment: I'm not sure about that. You should read bunyan documentation. Could you please accept my answer as the correct answer?